# What will be the correct word for "my siblings and me"?

Tags: word-request

I cannot come up with a word which will count my siblings and myself.

I am trying to denote a set (which includes my siblings and me). Help me.

Comment: What do you mean a set?

Comment: @Cardinal I mean mathematical set. for example siblings is a set of my brothers and sisters.  In that set, I want to include myself. But what will be the correct English word for such a set.

Comment: Do you mean **a set of family members** including you and your siblings ?

Comment: Is there such a word in your language?

Comment: @user3169 Do you address me?

Comment: @Cardinal No, I was asking the OP. By asking for a (single I assume) word, I wondered if another language has such a single word. I kind of doubt English has one in regular use.

Comment: Yes, I doubt English has a word that means "your siblings and you". If it is clear from context, you might consider "we" and "us".

Comment: You could try "my generation" if it's clear from context that the set is limited to your immediate family.

Answer (score 6):

To my knowledge, English has no word that would specifically identify you and your siblings as a set. You might use something like "my parents' children", but that is a bit awkward as well as impersonal.

Depending on whether you are part of the subject of the sentence or an object, "my siblings and I" or "my siblings and me" would be acceptable and understandable. For example, as a sentence's subject, you might say:

> Yesterday **my siblings and I** played a game.

As an object, you could say:

> Our childless uncle left his estate to **my siblings and me** in his will.

Answer (score 5):

In general to an American English speaker, "My siblings and I" sounds very natural to say.  There may be a better word if you give us more information about what you are trying to say.